# In Redshift: (\s|\+) pattern does NOT work, but ([\s]|[\+]) does. Are they the same?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, amazon-redshift

When I run this query in Redshift:

```
select distinct bot, case when bot ~ 'Web(\s|\+)Downloader' then 1 else 0 end isbot from bots
```

I get this error:

> Invalid operation: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occured while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'Web(s|+>>>HERE>>>)Downloader'.

However, when I change the regex pattern to this:

```
Web([\s]|[\+])Downloader
```

Then the query runs without error.

I tested both versions of the pattern here: https://regex101.com/

And they seem to behave the same.

But I wanted to post here and verify if they are indeed the same thing and one just happens to work for Redshift.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but did you try double escaping the backslash?

Comment: Doing that would escape the escape character and therefore search for a backslash and that's not what i need. Thanks

Comment: No errror, but does it work at all? I suspect you need `'Web(\\s|\\+)Downloader'` or just `'Web[\\s+]Downloader'`

Answer (score 1):

The `'Web(\s|\+)Downloader'` string literal contains string escape sequences, `\s` and `\+`. Since these string escape sequences are unknown (`\r` is a carriage return, `\n` is a newline, but `\s` and `\+` do not exist) the backslashes are removed and the *string* that results after parsing the string literal is `Web(s|+)Downloader`. So, `+` turns into a *1 or more* quantifier. Since quantifying the alternation operator is forbidden, the exception is thrown. Also, `s` starts matching `s`, not a whitespace. `'Web([\s]|[\+])Downloader'` works without errors, but does not match `Web Downloader`, but should match `WebsDownloader` as the pattern gets parsed by the engine as `Web([s]|[+])Downloader` where `[+]` matches a literal `+` (since it is inside a bracket expression) and `[s]` matches `s`.

You need

```
'Web(\\s|\\+)Downloader'
```

Or,

```
'Web[\\s+]Downloader'
```

See the [Amazon Redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html):

> To search for strings that include metacharacters, such as ‘. * | ? ‘, and so on, escape the character using two backslashes (' \\ ').